# Django TypeError objects is not iterable in Templates

Tags: python, django

I have two models one is club details and the other is player structure. so my plan is to based on the club iteration which has values like'test', 'odi', 'listA' i need to represent its respective player structure in my Django template.

**models.py**

```
class Clubstate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PlayerStructure(models.Model):
    clubstate =  models.ForeignKey('Clubstate', on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='clubstate')
    country = models.ForeignKey('TeamStructure', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,  related_name='identifier1')
    firstname =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname  =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
    imageUri =   models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', verbose_name='image')
    JerseyNumber = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + self.lastname
```

In **views.py** I'm using DetailView to represent the data.

```
class PlayerStatistics(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'Clubstate_details'
    model = models.Clubstate
    template_name = 'CricketDetails/playerstatistics_details.html'
```

**Template html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               {% for club in Clubstate_details  %}
                <h1>{{club.name</h1>

               {% endfor %} 
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My thought, logic is like

```
{% for club in clubs %}
    {{club.name}}
    {{club.player_structure.firstname}}
    {{club.player_structure.lastname}}
{% endfor%}
```

So that for indivdual club i get its respective player structure.
I get `TypeError: 'Clubstate' object is not iterable` error.
Hope that makes sense...

Comment: May not be the reason for your error, but you got a typo in `<h1>{{club.name</h1>` -> `}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detail view won't give a list of items, instead it gives a single view only so change the DetailView to ListView and iterate through the output

```
class PlayerStatistics(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'Clubstate_details'
    model = models.Clubstate
    template_name = 'CricketDetails/playerstatistics_details.html'
```

if you want detail view can get it by

```
{{ Clubstate_details.name }}
```

with DetailView

FK instance can be accessed by

```
{% for obj in Clubstate_details.playerstructure_set.all %}

{{ obj.firstname }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I refer the player structure fields using the foreign key ?

Comment: I want the club name to be iterable so I will need to use the list view. But how can I correlate with club and player structure using the foreign key? Like I. mentioned in the question about the logic I thought.

Comment: I checked in my code I see nothing in my web. May i know what is ```playerstructure_set.all``` mean? Is it the model name of the playerstructure with all small letters?

Comment: it is the reverse look up of FK, this you have to test in your detailview

Comment: I'm not sure why but i couldnt access FK fields.

Comment: Table1(primarykey) - Table 2(FK) I could access using related_names. As per the question  I have a new Table3(primarykey) - Table 2(FK) is showing blank.

Comment: Is it a data related issue? But i see the data in Django Admin